# Mostrar Datos de SQL en TextBox

Tags: c#

En este código me muestra 3 datos con el mismo numero de folio y el mismo departamento, con la ayuda de un `listBox`, sin embargo quiero que tambien se muestren en 3 textbox que tengo (Obviamente los datos que mostraran son 3 diferentes, como el `listBox` )

```
       public void listSMTQA()
    {
        DateTime hoy = DateTime.Now;
        string folioid = hoy.ToString("ddMMyy");
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("Select SMT from tbl_Issues where folio='" + folioid + "' and Dpto='Quality'", cn);
        SqlDataReader leer;
        leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
        while (leer.Read() == true)
        {
            listBox3.Items.Add(leer[0].ToString());
            //Aqui quiero que los muestre tambien
            textBox5.Text = leer["SMT"].ToString();
            textBox6.Text = leer["SMT"].ToString();
            textBox7.Text = leer["SMT"].ToString();
        }
        cn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Sugerencias breves, no relacionadas a tu pregunta: 1) Evita usar conexiones globales 2) Usa los objetos de tipo `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` y `SqlDataReader` dentro de bloques `using` para liberar los recursos apropiadamente, 3) Usa parámetros en vez de concatenar valores directamente en tu cadena SQL.

Comment: Gracias, lo de los parámetros si tengo conocimiento, pero lo de `using` no, lo tomare mucho en cuenta staan

Comment: @CarlosR93 Podrías agregar una variable como índice, al momento que realice el `while` evalúas que valor tiene el índice y llenas a un determinado `TextBox`, como lo hacer para llenar el `ListBox`.

Comment: ¿Cual es el error?

Comment: La instruccion `leer.Read()` es un ciclo que lee una fila del query a la vez, por lo que la referencia `leer["SMT"]` es al mismo registro hasta que se cumpla el ciclo. Deberias usar un index para saber a que textbox asignarle valor, o bien usar un `SqlDataAdapter` en vez del `SqlDataReader`, ya que ese devuelve un `DataTable` y es mas facil de manipular para hacer este tipo de asignaciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado si ya tiene en el ListBox los item de la base de datos de ahí mismo los puede sacar para asignarselos a sus textbox, le dejo un pequeño código quizá le sea de utilidad. Saludos.

```
 public void listSMTQA()
{
    DateTime hoy = DateTime.Now;
    string folioid = hoy.ToString("ddMMyy");
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("Select SMT from tbl_Issues where folio='" + folioid + "' and Dpto='Quality'", cn);
    SqlDataReader leer;
    leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
    while (leer.Read() == true)
    {
        listBox3.Items.Add(leer[0].ToString());

    }
    cn.Close();
//Si ya tienes todos los valores en la lista, entonces los puedes
//sacar de ahí también, y no te saldran repetidos y podrás agregar
//el primero, el segundo y el tercero al elemento que quieras.
//listBox3.Items[0].Text; le pasarás el texto que es visible para el cliente
//si le pasas listBox3.Items[0].Value; le pasarás el valor que le agregaste
//  ese atributo y no es visible para el cliente. 

if(listBox3.Items.Count > 0){

}
        textBox5.Text = listBox3.Items[0].Text;
        textBox6.Text = listBox3.Items[1].Text;
        textBox7.Text = llistBox3.Items[2].Text;
}
```